# Rails has_many with an integer primary key and a string foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-keys, nosql

I have three rails objects: `User`, `DemoUser` and `Stats`. Both the `User` and the `DemoUser` have many stats associated with them. The `User` and `Stats` tables are stored on Postgresql (using ActiveRecord). The `DemoUser` is stored in redis. The id for the `DemoUser` is a (random) string. The id for the `User` is a (standard-rails) incrementing integer.

The `stats` table has a `user_id` column that can contain either the `User` id or the `DemoUser` id. For that reason, the `user_id` column is a string, rather than an integer.

There isn't an easy way to translate from the random string to an integer, but there's a very easy way to translate the integer id to a string (`42 -> "42"`). The ids are *guaranteed* not to overlap (there won't be a `User` instance with the same id as a `DemoUser`, ever).

I have some code that manages those stats. I'd like to be able to pass over a `some_user` instance (which can either be a `DemoUser` or a `User`) and then be able to use the `id` to fetch `Stats`, update them etc. Also would be nice to be able to define a `has_many` for the `User` model, so I can do things like `user.stats`

However, operations like `user.stats` would create a query like

`SELECT "stats".* FROM "stats" WHERE "stats"."user_id" = 42`

which then breaks with `PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer`

**Is there a way to either let the database (Postgresql), or Rails do auto-translation of the ids on JOIN?** (the translation from integer to string should be simple, e.g. `42 -> "42"`)

**EDIT**: updated the question to try to make things as clear as possible. Happy to accept edits or answer questions to clarify anything.

Comment: Wouldn't it make a lot more sense for `stats.user_id` to also be a string? Then your database would make sense and your problem would go away.

Comment: `stats.user_id` is a string... And I wouldn't want to change `user.id` to be a string, or it could create a whole raft of unforeseen issues...

Comment: So `stats.user_id` is a string which matches the string `id` from your other database. But you don't want to change your `users.id` to a string even though it really is a string that comes from your other database? Change it to match reality and deal with the side effects. What happens if the external `id` ends up as something like `'4ed6aa9f30f1b90927000001'` or some other non-numeric string? Your schema **must** match your data or you'll just have a big pile of confusion. Either you use the external `id`s everywhere (with proper types) or you need a table to map them.

Comment: I think you misunderstand things. Perhaps I didn't explain properly? `stats.user_id` is a string, which can be `"234"` (matching the `users.id` of `234`), or an external string `"abc"` which matches an id on a NoSQL database used within the same codebase.

Comment: You have two separate sets of users stored in two separate databases? Then you need to mirror them and link their `id`s explicitly. I have a similar situation: MongoDB and PostgreSQL. Each has its own notion of a user with their own `id` formats. Each user in MongoDB corresponds with a user in PostgreSQL and vice versa. The correspondence is tracked by storing the MongoDB user `id` in a text column in the PostgreSQL user table.

Comment: But in my case they are independent. Apart from the fact that both store stats using the `stats` table... I don't have any need for mapping between users or anything like that. It would be a huge overkill.

Comment: I think you need to describe your data better. If you're really trying to store two completely different things in one column then you have a big mess on your hands.

Comment: I don't think they are completely different things - they are both the user ids (just that those ids come from different places). The ids themselves are easily translatable e.g. `42 -> "42"` (a `to_s` operation), and they don't clash...

Comment: That they come from different places means that they are completely different things. They might not clash today but it is almost certain to happen in the future. Do it right the first time, short cuts and quick hacks tend to backfire.

Comment: I updated the question with more info. I don't think they are completely different things. They are both users and both have stats... their ids won't clash.

Comment: But they are completely different things. Just because you call them both "users" doesn't make them the same in database terms.

Comment: I do agree that on the data representation they are stored differently - they are stored in two different data stores. But conceptually they are not completely different things - they are almost exactly the same. It's not just calling them "users" - they *are* users.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a foreign key between two types that don't have built-in equality operators.

The correct solution is to change the string column to be an integer.

---

In your case you *could* create a user-defined `=` operator for `varchar = string`, but that would have messy side effects elsewhere in the database; for example, it would allow bogus code like:

```
SELECT 2014-01-02 = '2014-01-02'
```

to run without an error. So I'm not going to give you the code to do that. If you truly feel it's the only solution (which I don't think is likely to be correct) then see [`CREATE OPERATOR`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createoperator.html) and [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html).

Comment: I wouldn't want to overload the entire `=` operator in postgres. That's for sure. I wonder if there's a way to translate from integer to strings only on this table though (because the translation is very simple `42 -> "42"`). I can do this translation in Rails, but then I don't "enjoy" some of the sugar that Rails provides for handling relationships.

Comment: @gingerlime No, you can't do that per-table. Just fix the column definition. If you *really* can't fix the app & column type, maybe you need a simply-updatable view to convert the int col to char for the buggy app? Worst case keep the text column and have a `BEFORE` trigger cast it to integer and copy the value to a second column of type integer, making that one the foreign key. But I really can't imagine a reason for doing this.

Comment: Thanks Craig. upvoted your answer. Looks like I ended up solving this on the application layer (see my answer). The solution isn't so complicated, it just doesn't fit 100% with the built-in way in rails to define foreign key relationships automatically. But I can mimic most of the functionality easily enough. I was just curious if there was by any chance a way to do this on the DB layer, but looks like it's not worth the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to have separate `user_id` and `demo_user_id` columns in your `stats` table. The `user_id` would be an integer that you could use as a foreign key to the `users` table in PostgreSQL and the `demo_user_id` would be a string that would link to your Redis database. If you wanted to treat the database properly, you'd use a real FK to link `stats.user_id` to `users.id` to ensure referential integrity and you'd include a CHECK constraint to ensure that exactly one of `stats.user_id` and `stats.demo_user_id` was NULL:

```
check (user_id is null <> demo_user_id is null)
```

You'll have to fight ActiveRecord a bit to properly constrain your database of course, AR doesn't believe in fancy things like FKs and CHECKs even though they are necessary for data integrity. You'd have to keep `demo_user_id` under control by hand though, some sort of periodic scan to make sure they link up with values in Redis would be a good idea.

Now your `User` can look up stats using a standard association to the `stats.user_id` column and your `DemoUser` can use `stats.demo_user_id`.

Comment: We do normally use foreign key constraints enforced in PG (using the foreigner gem). In this case, it's the exception - because we treat this the same as Redis - we can't maintain referential integrity outside of PG very easily. In fact, if it weren't for memory-constraints - we would probably keep those stats in redis. Using two separate columns is definitely possible, but makes things very messy in the code - i.e. always checking if this is a `User` or a `DemoUser` and then using the appropriate keys, or having some function that returns the type of key. This is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: But if you say things like `x.stats` then `x` takes care of that.

Comment: yes, that's possible. The current codebase doesn't exactly work this way. The various objects that manage stats pass a user id to reference different data objects (stats is just a simplification of several similar objects). Plus, my own [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26212710/305019) already does this without adding a 2nd column, and I know you're quite firm against the referential integrity issues and future problems, but I can't see how my solution is much worse...

Comment: ...thanks for your patience by the way, I'm genuinely trying to understand the trade-offs - not being stubborn for the sake of it.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, my 'solution' is not to use a `has_many` in Rails, but I can define some helper functions in the models if necessary. e.g.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def stats
    Stats.where(user_id: self.id.to_s) 
  end
  # ...
end
```

also, I would define some helper scopes to help enforce the `to_s` translation

```
class Stats < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_user_id, -> (id) { where(user_id: id.to_s) }
  # ...
end
```

This should allow calls like

`user.stats` and `Stats.for_user_id(user.id)`

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstood a detail of your issue before because it was buried in the comments.

(I strongly suggest *editing your question* to clarify points when comments show that there's something confusing/incomplete in the question).

You seem to want a foreign key from an integer column to a string column because the string column might be an integer, or might be some unrelated string. *That's* why you can't make it an integer column - it's not necessarily a valid number value, it might be a textual key from a different system.

The typical solution in this case would be to have a synthetic primary key and two `UNIQUE` constraints instead, one for keys from each system, plus a `CHECK` constraint preventing both from being set. E.g.

```
CREATE TABLE my_referenced_table (
   id serial,
   system1_key integer,
   system2_key varchar,
   CONSTRAINT exactly_one_key_must_be_set 
     CHECK (system1_key IS NULL != system2_key IS NULL),
   UNIQUE(system1_key),
   UNIQUE(system2_key),
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   ... other values ...
);
```

You can then have a foreign key referencing `system1_key` from your integer-keyed table.

It's not perfect, as it doesn't prevent the same value appearing in two different rows, one for `system1_key` and one for `system2_key`.

So an alternative might be:

```
CREATE TABLE my_referenced_table (
   the_key varchar primary key,
   the_key_ifinteger integer,
   CONSTRAINT integerkey_must_equal_key_if_set
     CHECK (the_key_ifinteger IS NULL OR (the_key_ifinteger::varchar = the_key)),
   UNIQUE(the_key_ifinteger),
   ... other values ...
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_referenced_table_copy_int_key()
RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT
AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.the_key ~ '^[\d]+$' THEN
     NEW.the_key_ifinteger := CAST(NEW.the_key AS integer);
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER copy_int_key
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON my_referenced_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_referenced_table_copy_int_key();
```

which copies the integer value if it's an integer, so you can reference it.

All in all though I think the whole idea is a bit iffy.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this together Craig. I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear. I'm not entirely sure what to change to make it clearer though. As far as this answer - I'm not sure I fully understand it to be honest - would the application be able to refer to the same column/key? Otherwise - if the application needs to be aware of two different keys, then it doesn't achieve what I want unfortunately. But maybe it's just my poor understanding.

Comment: @gingerlime Well, in the second example you're just duplicating the value of the text keys into a second column if they're integers, so you can create a FK reference to it.

Comment: But then the app still needs to reference two different foreign keys, which is what I'm trying to avoid. Sorry if I can't explain this clearly. I will try to update the question - even though it's a little hard to explain without getting into too much detail (or I'm just not terribly good at explaining this - which is more likely)

Comment: I revised the question. Hope it clears any confusion and explains things better(?)

Comment: I'm thinking that we could probably get away with separate `user_id int` and `demo_user_id text` columns in `stats`. Ideally with an "exactly one is NULL" constraint but the Rails ideology will make you fight for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have a solution for your problem, but maybe not a massively better one:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :stats, primary_key: "id_s"

  def id_s
    read_attribute(:id).to_s
  end

end
```

Still uses a second virtual column, but maybe more handy to use with Rails associations and is database agnostic.